# How do I suppress the error message from a failed redirection in UNIX?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to make my code return either the number of lines in the file `gold` or return `0` if the file doesn't exist. I will have another line later which may create the file `gold`, but I don't want the error message saying the file doesn't exist to show.

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 User None      9 Mar 27 01:00 X -> /dev/null`

`wc -l< ~/PA2/rooms/treasureRoom/gold 2> ~/X/blank || echo 0`

With the code as it is, it returns the error message and then `0`.

```
$ wc -l< ~/PA2/rooms/treasureRoom/gold 2> ~/X/blank || echo 0
-bash: /home/User/PA2/rooms/treasureRoom/gold: No such file or directory
0
```

How do I suppress the error from showing?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is part of a script, in which case you can use a shell function:

```
function line_count {
    typeset filename="$1"
    if [[ -a "$filename" && -f "$filename" ]]
    then
        wc -l < "$filename"
    else
        echo 0
    fi
}
```

In the conditional, the `-a` checks the file exists, and `-f` checks it's a plain file (not a directory or device).

An even simpler solution, if you're going to create the file `gold` anyway, is to `touch` it beforehand, which creates it as a 0-byte file if doesn't exist.  **Caveat**: if the file exists, touching it updates its last-modified time:

```
touch ~/PA2/rooms/treasureRoom/gold
wc -l < ~/PA2/rooms/treasureRoom/gold
```

Comment: Why not only use `-f`? It'll return false if the file doesn't exist, so there's no reason for a prior `-a`.

Comment: Also, note the entry in the last table in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the function keyword.

Comment: BTW, one can run `>>file` as its own command with similar results to `touch` but less performance overhead (since no executable external to the shell needs to be involved).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As for `-f` and omitting `-a`, you're correct.  Regarding the `function` keyword, the syntax I've used is the second replacement syntax in the chart you've linked.  This is more modern, and when working with other shells (ksh, probably zsh) the `function` syntax uses different and preferable variable scoping behavior in those shells.

Comment: The syntax you used is the second replacement in the _first_ chart; my intent was to draw your attention to the _third_ chart. If one wants local variables, the only reliable way to make it happen is to declare them explicitly. (Even in ksh, `function` changes the meaning of `typeset`, so one still needs to use `typeset`; might as well go the more portable-amongst-recent-shells route and use `local`, which even ash and dash support with POSIX-standard declaration syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Put the code with the redirection you want to silence in a group, and redirect stderr for the whole command group.

```
{ wc -l <~/PA2/rooms/treasureRoom/gold; } 2>/dev/null || echo 0
```